# Casting and wrappers: some strange cases

Tags: java, casting, wrapper

Look at this... this evening I was trying to cast some primiteves to wrappers when I found that:

```
Integer i = (Integer)4;
Integer i = (Integer)4f; // Doesn't compile!
```

But if I rewrite the second line:

```
Integer i2 = (int)4f; // Then it compiles
```

What's the difference? Why should I be able to cast with a wrapper class in the first case, but not in the second?

Answer (score 5):

here

```
Integer i = (Integer)4f;
```

youre casting a float primitive to an Integer wrapper - they dont fit. this has nothing to do with autoboxing either. even with explicit boxing, this still wont compile:

```
Integer i = (Integer)(Double.valueOf(4f));
```

while here:

```
Integer i2 = (int)4f;
```

you casting a float primitive to an int primitive (truncating in the process) and then java auto-boxes that into an Integer for you